# PHP SQL selecting the same column with two different values

Tags: php, sql, join

So I have two tables with price information.

`Table_01` has the an ID and a price and `table_02` has extra information with IDs and different group prices.

**table_01**

```
---------
id price
---------
1  300
2  300
3  300
```

**table_02**

```
----------------
id group price
----------------
1    1     50
2    1     50
2    2     100
3    1     50
```

What I would like to output in HTML

```
----------------------------------------
ID PRICE GROUP1 PRICE GROUP2 PRICE
-----------------------------------------
1   300      50         -
2   300      50        100
3   300      50         -
```

I've successfully queried everything but "GROUP2 PRICE". I use this SQL command

```
SELECT table_01.id, table_02.price AS saleprice, table_01.price
FROM table_01
LEFT JOIN table_02
ON table_01.id=table_02.id AND table_02.group= '1'
```

I'm not really sure how I would query that second group. I can easily swap out that the `"='1'"` to `"='2'"` but I would like to somehow get both of them.

Comment: If the numbers of groups is known (and small), than you may use the solution of Jan Turoň. Otherwise you need a pivot. Do you use mysql, postgres ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this?

```
SELECT table_01.id, table_01.price, t21.price AS 'GROUP1 PRICE',   
t22.price AS 'GROUP2 PRICE'  
FROM table_01   
LEFT JOIN table_02 t21  
ON table_01.id=t21.id AND t21.group= '1'  
LEFT JOIN table_02 t22  
ON table_01.id=t22.id AND t22.group= '2'
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Worked like a charm!  Ty so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Just join table_02 twice:

```
SELECT table_01.id, table_01.price, t02a.price price1, t02b.price price2
FROM table_01 
LEFT JOIN table_02 t02a ON table_01.id=t02a.id AND t02a.group='1' 
LEFT JOIN table_02 t02b ON table_01.id=t02b.id AND t02b.group='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use GROUP BY statement

Comment: I don't think that this works. A GROUP BY statement doesn't convert rows to columns.